# How to create an object from array by calling back create action? Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am stuck at: I need to create a text and the same way I need to create a list of words out of the created text. So what I did:

I created create action in my text controller:

```
def create
  @text = Text.new(text_params)

  if @text.save
    redirect_to text_path(@text), notice: "Text successfully created"
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Here is the form for creating a text:

```
<%= form_for @text do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Text name</label>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Description</label>
      <%= f.text_area :description%>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>

<%end%>
```

In the Text Model I created after_create callback:

```
class Text < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :words
  after_create :create_words

  def create_words

    @word = Word.new( word_params )

      @text.split(/\W+/)
      @text.each do |splitted|
          if splitted != @words.name
            splitted = @word
            @word.save
            redirect_to root_path
          else
            render :new
          end
      end
  end


def word_params
    params.require(:word).permit(:name, :translation)
 end

end
```

I am new to RoR and Please help me out to fix my issue. Basicly what I need is when I am creating text for instance a text is:

> I have a dog

should be placed on my `texts` table and each word:

> I, have, a, dog

should be placed in my `words` table in the database.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`redirect_to` is a routes helper that are available in controllers. So, you should just work on model object on your model class. update your `create_words` method with the following content.

```
class Text < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :words
  after_create :create_words


  private
    def create_words
      # self is the Text object in context 
      # i.e the Text object on which after_create is called
      words = self.description.split(/\W+/)
      words.each do |splitted|
        self.words.create(name: splitted, translation: '')
      end
    end

end
```

So every time you save save a `Text` object, `after_create :create_words` is triggered, which splits the `Text` object in context (`self`) and each word is iterated to create a new associated `Word` object on your `words` table.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's an excellent explanation. But it returns undefined method `split' for #<Text:0x007fd21d6655c0> I know if I am not wrong I need to define words which I did. But no success.

Comment: updated the answer.. it should be `self.description.split` (self is the Text object, i believe you're splitting the description attribute of the Text object) @neonamo

Comment: yes, you are very right! You are great! @sa77 And now I am facing this error unknown attribute 'text_id' for Word.

Comment: i think that should have been covered .. you should have a foreign key of texts table (i.e `text_id`) in your `words` table with `belongs_to :text` association on your `app/models/word.rb` file and `has_many :words, foreign_key: :text_id` on your `app/models/text.rb` file for this to work.

Comment: Yes, exactly rails g migration AddTextToWords text:references I just added. And finally it works!!! You are awesome! Thank you so much!!!